# Kotlin - Trying to use existing Fragment in a DialogFragment - Recyclerview does not display "No adapter attached; skipping layout"

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to reuse an existing Fragment and put it into a DialogFragment. Most of the layout displays correctly, except for a RecyclerView. Here is the code of the Fragment that is displaying correctly.

```
class ExercisesFragment : Fragment() {
    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): ExercisesFragment {
            return ExercisesFragment()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exercises, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        rc_exercises.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            adapter = ExerciseAdapter()
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to reuse `R.layout.fragment_exercises` here:

```
class AddExerciseDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exercises, container, false)
        //rc_exercises = view.findViewById(R.id.rc_exercises)
        rc_exercises.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            adapter = ExerciseAdapter()
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

When I run the application, the layout is displayed, except for the RecyclerView. Logcat shows the message:

E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout.

When I run the code in debug mode, I see that `rc_exercises` is null. I tried to explicitly assign `rc_exercises`:

`rc_exercises = view.findViewById(R.id.rc_exercises)` but this causes an error "Val cannot be reassigned.

Should I make `rc_exercises` a Var? If so, I cannot figure out how to. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Check that in the first case you are attaching adapter in onActivityCreated and in second case you are doing it in onCreateView.

Comment: @Lenin
I added 
`override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        rc_exercises.adapter = ExerciseAdapter()
    } `
to `AddExerciseDialogFragment` but I am getting the same errors.